# Find the necessary and sufficient condition for $A^m\to0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ matrix on $\mathbb{C}$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition for $A^m\to0$ as $m\to\infty$.

My thought: I think it should be that eigenvalues of $A$ are less than $1$. But I am unable to prove it.

Comment: Are you unable to prove necessity, sufficiency, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use $l_2$ norm for matrix as

> $$\|A\|=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|^2}\tag{1}$$

First we define inequality for matrix as

> Let $A$ be $n\times n$ matrix on $\mathbb{C}$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ non-negative matrix.
>   $$A\leqslant B \hspace{5 mm} \text{iff } \hspace{5 mm} |a_{ij}|\leqslant b_{ij}, \hspace{2 mm} i,j=1,\cdots,n \tag{2}$$

We can prove following lemmas.

> **Lemma:**
>
> $1. \hspace{2 mm} A\to0 \iff \|A\|\to0$
>
> $2.\hspace{2 mm} A\leqslant B\implies \|A\|\leqslant\|B\|$
>
> $3.\hspace{2 mm} A\leqslant B\implies A^m\leqslant B^m$
>
> $4.\hspace{2 mm}\|AB\|\leqslant\|A\|\|B\|$
>
> $5.\hspace{2 mm} A\leqslant B\land B\to0\implies A\to0$

Prove of $1$ and $2$ are trivial.

Prove of $3$:
We only prove $m=2$ and rest follows from induction.
$$|(A^2)_{ij}|=\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{kj}\right|\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|a_{ik}||a_{kj}|\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}b_{ik}b_{kj}=(B^2)_{ij}$$

Prove of $4$:
\begin{align}
\|AB\|^2&=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right|^2
\\
&\leqslant\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|a_{ik}|^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n|b_{kj}|^2\right)\tag{Cauchy-Schwarz}
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}\left(\sum\limits_{k,l=1}^n|a_{ik}|^2|b_{lj}|^2\right)
\\
&=\sum\limits_{i,k=1}^{n}|a_{ik}|^2\sum\limits_{l,j=1}^n|b_{lj}|^2
\\
&=\|A\|^2\|B\|^2
\\
\end{align}
Prove of $5$:

By $1$ and $2$, $\|A\|\to0$. And by $1$ again, $A\to0$.

The following theorem is the key to prove.

> **Theorem:**
>   $A^m \to 0$ as $m\to\infty$ iff any eigenvalue of $A$, $|\lambda_i|<1, i=1,\cdots,n$.

Prove:

Let $J_A$ be Jordan Canonical Form and there is invertible $P$ such that 
$$
P^{-1}AP=J_A=\pmatrix{J_{\lambda_1}\\&\ddots \\&& J_{\lambda_l}}
$$
where $\lambda_i,1\leqslant i\leqslant l$ are distinct eigenvalues of $A$ and $J_{\lambda_i}$ are Jordan Blocks.

If all $|\lambda_i|<1$, then for any $|\lambda_i|$, there is a $\mu_i$ such that $|\lambda_i|<\mu_i<1$. So
$$
J_A=\pmatrix{J_{\lambda_1}\\&\ddots \\&& J_{\lambda_l}}\leqslant \pmatrix{\mu_1 \hspace{5 mm}1\\\ddots \\& \mu_{n-1} \hspace{5 mm}1 \\& \hspace{10 mm}\mu_n }=S
$$
Note that $\mu_i$ are set to be all distinct (even for same $\lambda_i$) so that $S$ is diagonalizable. Let
$$
Q^{-1}SQ=\text{diag}(\mu_1\cdots\mu_n)
$$
So
$$
S^m=Q\text{diag}(\mu_1^m\cdots\mu_n^m)Q^{-1}\to0
$$
By lemma $3$
$${J_A}^m\leqslant S^m$$
And by lemma $5$
$${J_A}^m\to0$$
Thus
$$A^m=P{J_A}^mP^{-1}\to0$$

Conversely if ${A}^m\to0$, then 
$${J_A}^m=P^{-1}A^mP\to0$$
So $|\lambda_i|<1, i=1,\cdots,n$.

Comment: S, as defined, is not diagonalizable.

Comment: No, it does not: its Jordan form has exactly the same number of blocks and of the same sizes as $A$, simply because you defined it that way.

Comment: What you want is not what you did: you want to replace each block $J_{\lambda_i}$ in $J_A$ by one with the same off-diagonal entries and diagonal entries positive, distinct, all larger that $|\lambda_i|$ and smaller that $1$.

Comment: Read what you wrote. If $J_{\mu_i}$ is a Jordan block of size larger than $1$ it is not diagonalizable.

Comment: What you need to do is something like «Let $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ be pairwise-different numbers such that $\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq l}|\lambda_i|<\mu_j<1$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$»

Comment: I know what you meant: the problem was that what you *wrote* meant something different. :-) (It still is quite confusing, in my opinion)

Answer (score 7):

Certainly when $\| A\| <1$, since in that case 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty } \| A^n \| \leq \lim_{n\to \infty } \| A \|^n = 0
$$
Therefore $A^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Conversely, if $A^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, continuity of the norm gives that $\|A^n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: For your «conversely» to be the proof of the converse, you'd need to show how to conclude that $\Vert A\Vert<1$ :-)

Comment: The true "converse statement" in this case is that if $A^n \to 0$, then *there exists a submultiplicative norm* $|\cdot|$ such that $|A| < 1$.  It is not necessarily the case, however, that $\|A\|< 1$ for *any* choice of submultiplicative norm.

Answer (score 3):

We know from the theorem on Jordan decompositions there exist a diagonalizable matrix $D$ and a nilpotent matrix $N$ such that $A=D+N$ and $DN=ND$, and then $A^k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}D^{k-i}N^{i}$. Since $N^n=0$, this means that in fact $$A^k=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{k}{i}D^{k-i}N^{i}.$$
Use what you know about diagonalizable matrices to conclude that the condition that the eigenvalues of $A$ —which are, as you know, the same as those of $D$— be of absolute value less than $1$ is a sufficient condition; notice this last expression has a fixed number of terms, independent of $k$.

If there is an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|\geq1$ and $v\in\mathbb C^n$ is a non-zero vector such that $Av=\lambda v$, then we have $A^kv=\lambda^kv$, which has norm not going to zero if $k$ goes to infinity. This implies that $A^k$ does not go to zero as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: This does not work because there is items with $\binom{k}{i}$ that are large enough so that even $\lambda_i<1$ can not guarantee it approaching $0$.

Comment: @mathcraze, for large $k$, we have $\binom{k}{i}\lambda^k\sim k^i\lambda^k$ and $k^i\lambda^k\to 0$ a $k$ grows if $|\lambda|<1$. You should probably check your computation!

Comment: Mariano, you should state it in the proof to make it clear.